# Nuxt.js: What is the best or practical way to save the Query in Vuex even after refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm creating a Reddit-like web application using Nuxt Frontend along with Node-Mongo Backend.

But since I lack practical programming knowledge, I'm having a little trouble with handling Article (or post) list with queries.

Below is the description of how the app should work:

**(1) Route: /page/index.vue**
Using `asyncData({app, query})`, I request data from the backend with axios. 
Article list can be sorted with `genre`, and `sort=${sortQuery}`.
I have no problem retrieving the sorted article list from the backend using `watchQuery: true` provided by Nuxt.

**(2) Route: /page/:id/index.vue**
This is where users can read the individual article. 
When the page is loaded, `asyncData` is executed to retrieve `currentArticle` data as well as `ArticleList`. 
When users organically move from `/page` to `/page/:id`, article list sorted by the query is preserved since `Query` has been stored in Vuex Store.

**The Problem:**
However, when users refresh the page, it is not possible to retrieve the sorted article list, because the Vuex stored `Query` does not exist...

### And I'd like to preserve the last query used to re-load the article list from the backend even after refreshing or odd way of routing.

To solve this issue, I was thinking of storing Vuex `Query` in LocalStorage of the web, but I feel like there must be an easier and much more practical way to achieve this...

Could someone please leave a comment on how to resolve this problem practically?

Let me know if more information is needed!

Thank you for your time in advance :)

Comment: Look into localStorage and some of the Vuex-related packages, e.g. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass on the query parameters in nuxt link from the first page like:

`<nuxt-link :to="{ path: 'page', query: { genre: 'x' }}">My Article</nuxt-link>`

That way the sorting condition would be persisted in the url and you could link to or share it from anywhere/with anyone.

Comment: I was thinking of the same way as you mentioned. Would this be the best approach to acheive the goal?